# Fixed background in grouped UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, background

I have an app with an UINavigationController and two tableviews. When I switch between these two table views, I would like the background to remain static, so it doesn't change, but I don't have a clue on how to do this.

I was thinking of making the background of the two table views transparent and to add a UIViewController behind then with the desired static image as background. Is that a right approach? Or are there better or easier solutions? I'm working with storyboards btw.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're into animation, a frame change ain't all that bad to code out.  You could use a transparent background for the table, and insert an image view behind the two tables:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{
     [self.tableOne setFrame:CGRectMake(-320,0,self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
     [self.tableTwo setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
 }];
```

Of course frame is just one option.  Center works as well.

Comment: Thank you for your response but I've barely worked with animations and I don't know very much about how to implement then. Is there another easier way to do this?

Comment: Honestly, no.  This is infinitely easier than view controller containment.